# Do these sort of commenting lines have a name?

Tags: coding-style, comments

```
//
// These are my comments at the beginning...
//
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- <--- These?

SETUP;
DRAW;
END;
```

I did some searching but I found myself not knowing what to call them.

Comment: I would suggest they are just a visual thing - a way of quickly distinguishing from comments and code - i dont think they really have a name ... other than perhaps a separator

Comment: I have never seen a name for that, but it probably contains the word 'ugly'.

Comment: Agreed. The things you see in others' code.

Comment: Aren't they called *block comments*?

Comment: I call them "comment banners" or "dividers".  Like many things in life, done well they can be a wonderful way to visually organize code into major divisions.  Used poorly, they can be the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

If such a line must be given a name, call it an *ASCII Art divider*.
Such lines help guide the eye when flipping through a large printout, but only take up screen space in a modern editor, where syntax colouring is more effective.

(The multi-line comment as a whole is called a block comment, with or without such dividers.)